# Setting Helm custom source from the result of a search

Tags: helm, search, helm-sources

I want to be able to use the results of a regexp search as an helm source. The goal here is to find all the labels of a latex document, this in part because I find this useful but also to learn Helm and elisp.
Here is what I came up with:

```
(defun my/matches-in-buffer (regexp)
  "return a list of matches of REGEXP."
  (let ((matches))
    (save-match-data
      (save-excursion
          (save-restriction
            (widen)
            (goto-char 1)
            (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
              (push (substring (match-string 1) 7 -1) matches))))
      )
matches
))

(defun my/find-labels ()
(my/matches-in-buffer "\\(\\\\label{\\(.*\\)}\\)")
)
(setq label-helm-source
      '((name . "HELM label")
        (candidates . my/find-labels)
        (action . (lambda (candidate)
                    (message "%s" candidate)))))
(defun helm-label ()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources '(label-helm-source)))
```

However this does not seem to work as helm gives me no proposition when I do `M-x helm-labels`. On the other hand, executing `(my/find-labels)` in an org-mode file containing a `\label{test}` gives me the list with element `test` as expected.

What should I change in the code to have Helm use the results of the search from `my/find-labels` as a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right track, but are missing a couple of things.

The two most important ones are:

1. You need to wrap your candidate computation in `with-helm-current-buffer`; otherwise, Helm will search for your labels in the *Helm buffer* and not in the *buffer from which Helm was invoked*.
2. Ultimately, Helm will need to know where to jump to.  In order to achieve this, you can utilize its `(DISPLAY . REAL)` form of a candidate, where `DISPLAY` will be the label and `REAL` will be its position.

The two less important ones are:

1. Your candidates are in reverse order — you should `nreverse` them.
2. The `(substring (match-string 1) 7 -1)` part makes no sense, why the hardcoded 7?

Bearing these in mind, I came up with the following proof of concept:

```lisp
(defun my/matches-in-buffer (regexp)
  "Return a list of matches of REGEXP."
  (let ((matches))
    (save-match-data
      (save-excursion
        (save-restriction
          (widen)
          (goto-char 1)
          (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
            ;; (DISPLAY . REAL) candidate format
            (push (cons (match-string 1) (match-beginning 1)) matches)))))
    ;; Correct order of matches
    (nreverse matches)))

(defun my/helm-label-candidates ()
  "Compute candidates for `my/helm-label'."
  ;; Search in correct buffer
  (with-helm-current-buffer
    (my/matches-in-buffer "\\\\label{\\(.*\\)}")))

(defun my/helm-label-action (candidate)
  "Jump to CANDIDATE from `my/helm-label'."
  ;; Jump to candidate
  (goto-char candidate)
  (helm-highlight-current-line))

(defun my/helm-label ()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources '(((name . "HELM label")
                    (candidates . my/helm-label-candidates)
                    (action . my/helm-label-action)))))
```

There are of course several improvements to be made: help, persistent action, better handling of narrowed regions when jumping, etc.

Comment: Thanks this answers exactly my question. And the hard-coded 7 is the length of `\label{` because I wanted only the content and not the whole and I did not know how to do that with regexp. Your solution is a lot better. Thanks!